# Get a node from an entry using xPath in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I have to get a list of categories from a XML file that contains entries which have as childs some categories. 
I tried to use the following xPath

```
feed/entry/category
```

but I receive categories from both entries. How can i get categories for each entry?

The XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed>
    <entry>
        <id>1</id>
        <category term="note"></category>
        <category term="notebook"></category>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>2</id>
        <category term="note1"></category>
        <category term="notebook1"></category>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
feed/entry[N]/category
```

to access the categories of a specific entry with `N` being `1` or `2` in your case (or any other index in the more general case).